# Cannot run n98-magerun

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to install magerun on my magento server but I just cannot make it run properlly.

I followed all the instructions from https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

> ## #wget http:// files.magerun.net/n98-magerun-latest.phar -O n98-magerun.phar
>
> --2015-10-09 11:02:51--  http:// files.magerun.net/n98-magerun-latest.phar
>   Resolving files.magerun.net... 5.35.244.165
>   Connecting to files.magerun.net|5.35.244.165|:80... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
>   Length: 2787592 (2.7M) [application/octet-stream]
>   Saving to: `n98-magerun.phar'
>   100%[=============>] 2,787,592   9.09M/s   in 0.3s
>
> ## #md5sum n98-magerun.phar
>
> 158e64856535f10e2259e9431b81ed82  n98-magerun.phar
>
> ## #chmod +x ./n98-magerun.phar
>
> ## #./n98-magerun.phar --version
>
> y?

As you can see, as I try to get the version installed I just get this "y?", as response.

Can someone help me with this please, thanks in advance

Comment: did you raise an issue on the github from magerun itself?

Comment: Actually, I didn't. On my way!
[https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/issues/706](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/issues/706)

Comment: Problem was solved by setting "detect_unicode" to "Off". 

`php -d detect_unicode=Off n98-magerun.phar`

Comment: Yes it was, I forgot to answer here. Sorry for that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding **detect_unicode=Off** to the command. You can add this to your php.ini if you have access to it.

> Working command:
>
> ## php -d detect_unicode=Off n98-magerun.phar